# Can the child process affect parent process' environment?

Tags: c++, c, unix, process, environment-variables

What does "*the child inherits the parent's environment*" mean? Inherits by copying the whole environment, or inherits by receiving pointer to the same environment (somehow)?

---

Here's my scenario:

1. I have a running process `P` with its own environment (variables)
2. At some point, `P` executes `fork`
3. In the `0`-clone of the `if-statement` (a.k.a. in the child process `C`), an `execv` is executed
4. Both processes continue running independently.

So, in some moment, the application stops working fine. And the reason is - "broken" environment.

The interesting part is, that both environments are changed.. When I start the parent process and execute

```
$ cat /proc/PID/environ
```

for both - the parent and the process, everything is fine. Some hours later, the app stops working and when I execute the line above again (to check the environment), both are changed and a lot of environment variables are missing - only the standard ones are there (like `PWD`, `HOME`, `USER`, etc.).

How is this possible? And where could the the problem - in the child or in the parent?

---

***EDIT:*** Thanks all for the answers, +1 from me, as they were all correct ( @caf, @Saphrosit and @R..). The reason for this issue is really silly..

All environment variables were placed in `/etc/profile` which is executed AFTER LOGIN (that.. I didn't know).

Well, it appeared, that the issue have happened on restart of the machine. So, on start-up, the application is started again, but `/etc/profile/` is **not** executed/read. And this causes the bad behavior. And that's why the problem disappears on manual restart - once a `root` is logged in (through `ssh`), the environment variables from `/etc/profiles` are read, and when the parent process is restarted (by `root`), it's all fine - the environment variables are inherited.

Stupid mistake.

Comment: Do you ever call `wait` or `waitpid` from the parent? If not, the child will remain a zombie process after its termination.

Comment: Wild guess - maybe both died and were restarted, with the wrong environment? If so, you'll see that the PIDs have changed.

Comment: @ugoren - it's possible, I can't find info about this, yet. But even if it's like this - all environment variables are set in `/etc/profile`, they are not manually exported in the shell.. so, even if it's this, I can't imagine what could "break" the environment so badly

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev - yes, there's a `waitpid` in the parent. But how is this important? I mean, could this affect the environment somehow? (I know I need to read some more about daemons, I'm researching this right now :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child inherits a copy of the parent's environment at the moment of the `fork()`.  Subsequent changes to the environment in either process do not affect the other.

The only way you could alter this is by doing something very strange, like placing the environment in a `MAP_SHARED` area, or using `ptrace()`.  You'd know it if you did something like this, though.

Comment: Hm, I don't have such thing.. Well, then what could cause different output of `cat /proc/PID/environ` then.. Maybe, something had happened in the same time for both processes? The interesting part is, that when I "restart" only the child process, the problem still exists (as expected, as it inherits the parent's environment), and when I restart the parent process, everything starts working just fine. All variables are placed in `/etc/profile`, they are not manually exported in the shell. Any idea?

Comment: I'll accept your answer, as it answers directly my question (before the "scenario" description). I'll edit my question to add explanation what have caused the problem. Thanks.

Comment: How could you do it with `ptrace()`? There are no system calls involved when updating environment variables.

Comment: @Barmar: `PTRACE_POKEDATA` can directly alter the traced process's memory, which could be used to alter the environment.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming you were talking about the parent passively copying the child's environment changes, not the child deliberately changing the parent.

Answer (score 2):

...Or in both?

The child start with a duplicate of his parent environment, so cannot affect his parent one. So I don't think the child changed the environment of the father, but maybe the father changed his own.

Without knowing what exactly the program does it's very hard to say where is the problem...

Comment: Yes, I know I haven't shown any code, but the app is very complicated and I can't just extract 3 lines and say - "this breaks something". I'm looking for some hints what could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really nearly impossible to answer without more details, but I'm going to take a stab at it anyway?

Are you sure that the contents of the environment are actually valid at the time you call `fork`? It's certainly possible that you corrupted memory but that the parent has already obtained and cached copies of the variables it cares about at this point, and that only later does it break when it tries to re-get one. If this is the case, the environment should be broken in the child too, but the child might not care...

If that's not the issue, the only possibilities left on a working system seem to be that either the parent is getting restarted and you're not aware of it, or the parent corrupted its own environment after `fork`ing.

Otherwise, perhaps you have a swap partition on a broken device and the environment is getting swapped out and corrupted when it's swapped back in...?

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks for the effort (+1). I'll edit my question to add explanation about what have caused the issue. Yes, the problem was in bad environment before `fork`.. caused by really dummy mistake. See my edit, if you're interested in :) (I'll post it in 5 min)