# Opening Shell in New Directory

Tags: go

I am trying to make my shell cd into a directory. Is there a better way to do this? The only problem with this way is that my shell is a subprocess of the current shell. Making me have to exit twice.

```
package main

func main(){
  err = syscall.Chdir(os.Getenv("HOME") + "/dev")
  exitIfErr(err)
  err = syscall.Exec(os.Getenv("SHELL"), []string{""}, os.Environ())
  exitIfErr(err)
}
```

Comment: Another issue you might encounter is that the `SHELL` environment variable is not available on Windows.

Comment: Wait.  But don't you want to exec from your shell, to replace the outer shell process with your Go process?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351198/what-is-the-use-of-exec-command-in-the-shell-scripting

Comment: @dyoo you are right. I just want to tell my outer shell process to change directories. So how do I go about that?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for, to directly mutate the parent process from a child process, is doable.  Offhand, that would break process isolation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360679/can-the-child-process-affect-parent-process-environment  The best I can think of at the moment is _replacing_ the parent shell process with your Go program via a shell exec, and the Go program _replacing_ its process with the new shell process via the `Exec` call you're doing at the moment.  But if you're going to go through all that trouble, why not just `cd` from your parent shell process?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`os.Chdir`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Chdir) instead to change directories:

```
func Chdir(dir string) error
```

> Chdir changes the current working directory to the named directory. If there is an error, it will be of type `*PathError`.

Regarding the exec I'd recommend using the [`os/exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package to run your sub-process. It sorts out all kind of portability nuances between *nix systems and even windows as far as applicable.